# Why Doesn't Login Page In Vaadin Show Up When I'm Using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin

I have setup a basic Spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass")).roles("USER")
          .and()
          .withUser("user2").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass")).roles("USER")
          .and()
          .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass")).roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
          .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login").permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And a login page as well:

```
@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, viewport-fit=cover")
@Route("login")
@PageTitle("Login")
public class Login extends VerticalLayout {     
   /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Login(){
            LoginOverlay login = new LoginOverlay(); // 
            login.setAction("login"); // 
            login.setOpened(true); // 
            login.setTitle("Spring Secured Vaadin");
            login.setDescription("Login Overlay Example");
            add(login); 

        }
}
```

But when I access `localhost:8080` without logging in, then Spring will navigate me to `localhost:8080/login`.

The problem is that I'm expecting Vaadin's built in standard login layout. But nothing is appearing. Just a white empty page. Have I forgot something?

Comment: Have also a problem like this. Had to comment out `.anyRequest().authenticated()`.  Tried `.ignore` in `configure(WebSecurity web)` also with no luck.

Comment: Please note that you cannot in general rely on authentication based on request URLs for Vaadin views. Once you permit or ignore all requests URLs needed for the login view to function, then it will also be possible to open all other views without making requests to any other URLs. You must thus use a `BeforeEnterListener` on the Vaadin side to ensure unauthenticated users cannot open arbitrary views, as is shown in the tutorial linked from the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you forgot to override the method `configure(WebSecurity web)` in your `SecurityConfiguration` class, as it is explained in the tutorial [Setting up Spring Security for Vaadin applications](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/setting-up-spring-security):

```
/**
 * Allows access to static resources, bypassing Spring security.
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            // Vaadin Flow static resources // 
            "/VAADIN/**",

            // the standard favicon URI
            "/favicon.ico",

            // the robots exclusion standard
            "/robots.txt",

            // web application manifest // 
            "/manifest.webmanifest",
            "/sw.js",
            "/offline-page.html",

            // (development mode) static resources // 
            "/frontend/**",

            // (development mode) webjars // 
            "/webjars/**",

            // (production mode) static resources // 
            "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
}
```

I would recommend reading through that whole [tutorial series](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security), maybe you overlooked other things as well.

Comment: But I don't have these URL paths in my gradle project.

Comment: These are not paths defined by any `@Route`. they are used internally by vaadin. just add this method to the `SecurityConfiguration` and try it out.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working. But I get invalid JSON response from the server. I have read the manual, but the manual is not complete and have lack of information. e.g where do I get the class `new CustomRequestCache()` and the class `SecurityUtils` ?

Comment: Twese two classes are used in the example for the method `configure(HttpSecurity http)` - your implementation of that method **should be working without these changes**. For reference, the `CustomRequestCache` is used to save the original request before the user was redirected to the loginpage, so after login it will navigate to the page the user originally tried to navigate to. `SecurityUtils` is a custom helper class. You can see the implementations of both [here](https://github.com/vaadin-learning-center/spring-secured-vaadin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/paul/spring/app/security)